# Django Rest-Framework: How to cross object in ModelSerializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

So, I know `ModelSerializer` supports nested model object based on the foreign key in the current object. However, I am wondering how to do a cross join models with specific the field equals to another object?

i.e.

```
class classroom(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True, editable = False)

class student(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True, editable = False)
    classroom = models.ForeignKey(classroom, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now I would like to do a ModelSerializer with classroom model. The idea I would like to archive is returning `student.objects.filter(classroom = self.id)` [self is classrom]

How can I get the data from the student as well? (There is no ForeignKey in classroom targeting student)

```
class classroomSerializer(ModelSerializer):
# students = ??
class Meta:
    model = classroom
    fields = [
        'id',
        'students',
    ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define another serializer for your student model and refer to it in your classroom serializer.

```
class classroomSerializer(ModelSerializer):
students = studentserializer(many=True)
class Meta:
    model = classroom
    fields = [
      'id',
      'students'
    ]
```

And add a related_name in your student model

```
class student(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True, editable = False)
    classroom = models.ForeignKey(classroom, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='students')
```

Comment: But I can't tell which field should be used for matching the objects in the database.

Comment: I have modified my answer.. try specifying a related_name to control your reverse relations

Comment: Looks like it works, but I am still fixing the problem. I tried to follow http://gregblogs.com/tlt-how-to-retrieve-the-fields-of-a-related-model-from-a-django-rest-framework-endpoint/ but something wrong. May I ask that, does the related_name has to be same as the field name declared in the ModelSerializer?

Comment: Problem fixed. Thank you for the info.

Comment: You can also define a source directly in the serializer call in case you don't want the the related_name to be the same as the field. 
`students = studentserializer(source='<another_source' ,many=True)`